# Extracting data from new worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Just wanted to see if there is a way for me to automatically extract data from a newly created worksheet.

I have a tracker setup with a summary page that show the amount of cost and quantities for the month. I create a new worksheet for each day. However when I create the new worksheet, I have to manual change the formula.

The formula I am using is:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(CW6,'180321W'!$C$123:$G$126,1,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP(CW6,'180321W'!$C$123:$G$126,5,FALSE))
```

where '180321W' is the name of the worksheet. The next one would be '180322T' for the next day which then i would would go and change it manually in the summary page. Is there a way for me to set it up that when I create the new worksheet, it would change automatically?

Please see below summary page, worksheets at the bottom and the daily tracker page

[image: summary page]

[image: Worksheets]

[image: tracker page]

Comment: Extracting records from worksheet is very much possible through VBA (Macro). You simply write the Criteria to filter the data to be extracted and where you want to dump it, in the same workbook as new sheet or to other workbook?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rajesh. Yeah VBA is out of my league, might just stick to the manual. Same workbook but new sheets.